# How to translate SQL query in PostgreSQL to DB2. SQL SELECT query with CASE, COUNT & GROUP

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with the following data: [table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXabv.png)

When I use the below query in PostgreSQL, it works as expected

```
select 
  case when total = 0 or null                                 then 'skip'
       when round((score / total * 100) ,2) >= 91             then '>=91'
       when round((score / total * 100) ,2) between 80 and 90 then '>=80 & <=90'
       else                                                        'other' 
  end as perc,
  count(*)
from public.customer  
group by perc;
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYEj.png)

The same syntax does not work in db2.  I've tried all kinds of variations with no luck.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: No, both your query and the query in the answer will NOT be executed at all because you are trying to use the "total" column and the "score" column within your case when construct, but they are missing in the GROUP BY clause. This is forbidden. You either need to apply a aggregate function on them or remove the GROUP BY clause. It's unclear what exactly you want to do there. Please better show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @Dante Please, don't post pictures. Provide test data in a text form to have an ability to construct statements on your test data much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended to check if `total` be `NULL` inside your `CASE` expression.  If so, then you should be using `IS NULL` to do the check:

```sql
select 
    case when total = 0 or total is null                        then 'skip'
         when round((score / total * 100) ,2) >= 91             then '>=91'
         when round((score / total * 100) ,2) between 80 and 90 then '>=80 & <=90'
         else                                                        'other' 
    end as perc,
    count(*)
from public.customer  
group by perc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Db2 supports [Grouping by SELECT clause columns](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=nps-grouping-by-select-clause-columns) in so called "Netezza compatibility mode" only, which you may turn on setting the `SQL_COMPAT` global variable in your session.
You **must** use subselect (commented out) otherwise.

```
SET SQL_COMPAT = 'NPS';

WITH CUSTOMER (SCORE, TOTAL) AS
(
  VALUES
    (92.5, 100.0)
  , (92.5, 100.0)
  , (85.0, 100.0)
  , (83.0, 100.0)
  , (92.5, 100.0)
)
/*
SELECT PERC, COUNT (*) AS COUNT
FROM
(
  SELECT
  case 
    when coalesce (total, 0) = 0
      then 'skip'
    when round((score / total * 100) ,2) >= 91
       then '>=91'
    when round((score / total * 100) ,2) between 80 and 90
       then '>=80 & <=90'
    else 'other' 
  end as perc
  FROM CUSTOMER 
)
GROUP BY PERC
*/
SELECT
  case 
    when coalesce (total, 0) = 0
      then 'skip'
    when round((score / total * 100) ,2) >= 91
       then '>=91'
    when round((score / total * 100) ,2) between 80 and 90
       then '>=80 & <=90'
    else 'other' 
  end as perc
, COUNT (*) AS COUNT
FROM CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY PERC;
```

| PERC | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| >=80 & <=90 | 2 |
| >=91 | 3 |